# Implement conditional formatting like excel in XamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, xamdatagrid

[image]

I want to implement conditional formatting like this(attached) in XamDataGrid. In excel, we have conditional formatting which changes background of cell based on value at runtime.

is there any existing functionality for this in XamDataGrid. I know by default XamDataGrid supports conditional formatting, but its kind of based on static input. I want similar functionality as in excel on grid.

Thanks in advance!!